# How to make "fatal error"?

Tags: package-writing, documentclass-writing, error-writing

How do you make LaTeX stop/ abort the compilation and output a "fatal error"?

I know there are a couple of ways to produce errors/warnings:

- `\ClassError{class-name}{error-text}{help-text}`
- `\ClassWarning{class-name}{warning-text}`
- `\ClassWarningNoLine{class-name}{warning-text}`

and similarly for packages. But how do you make an error that causes there to be no output PDF? What is the command for making such an error? I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Willing to use expl3?  The l3msg module has `\msg_fatal`.  Section 11.4 of the current manual.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
  \msg_new:nnn {my~module}{errorName}{Reason~for~error}
  \msg_fatal:nn {my~module}{errorName}
\ExplSyntaxOff
No hello world. 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm willing to use expl3. Can you provide a generic example of how to use it?

Comment: Edited answer to show an example.

Answer (score 3):

The trick (which is also used by `expl3`) is to change TeX's interaction mode to one in which it'll not accept input from the terminal, and then ask for input from the terminal. For instance you can use `\PackageError` and afterwards `\batchmode \read-1to\foo`:

```
\documentclass{article}

% Throw error normally
\PackageError{Vebjorn}{You're not nice, so I quit}{}
% change interaction mode (if not yet in batchmode)
\batchmode
% ask for terminal input (which would be stored in the macro `\foo`)
\read-1 to \foo

\begin{document}
You'll never see this!
\end{document}
```

Comment: Tried both the accepted answer, and this one. Nice thing about this method is that once the initial error message is thrown, that's all, folks. No further messages.